# Why is running this code always displaying Running?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Maximize[{Tan[a], a + b + c == \[Pi], 
   Sin[a] + 3 Sin[b] Cos[c] == 0, \[Pi]/2 < c < \[Pi], 
   0 < a < \[Pi]/2, 0 < b < \[Pi]/2}, {a, b, c}] // FullSimplify
```

Why is running this code always displaying Running? No calculation results

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We calculate the max value of `a`, then `Tan[a]` since `Tan` is increasing in `0 < a < π/2`

```
max=Maximize[{a, a + b + c == π, 
  Sin[a] + 3 Sin[b] Cos[c] == 0, π/2 < c < π, 0 < a < π/2,
   0 < b < π/2}, {a, b, c}]
Tan[max // First] // FullSimplify
```

> `3/4`

Comment: That is to say, if the maximum value of the function cannot be obtained in one step, then use monotonicity to find the maximum value of the independent variable first

Answer (score 2):

Or use a numeric method

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

{max, arg} = 
 NMaximize[{Tan[a], a + b + c == π, 
     Sin[a] + 3 Sin[b] Cos[c] == 0, π/2 < c < π, 
     0 < a < π/2, 0 < b < π/2}, {a, b, c}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30] // N // Rationalize

(* {3/4, {a -> 0.643501, b -> 0.463648, c -> 2.03444}} *)
```